# C# WPF MediaElement : bad video quality

Tags: c#, wpf, video, mediaelement

I actualy develop a media player and I use the MediaElement control.
However, I have a big problem with the quality of videos. With some video, the image is blurred and pixelated.

[With a MediaElement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bheZY.jpg)

[With the Windows App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ029.jpg)

As you can see, the video quality is not at all the same on Windows and video player with MediaElement.

The video is a simple .avi...

Is there a was a way to improve the quality of the video?